# Read data from two client using Python TCP/IP

Tags: python, sockets

I want to read data from 2 client that read by 1 server. In my program just can read data from 1 client when I running all program in server and client. can you help me? I have search in internet to find any method that can help me out. Sorry for my bad english.

```
#server code
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 10000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.blind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    data=conn.recv(1)
    print data
conn.close()

#client1 code 
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

HOST = '192.168.43.57'
PORT = 10000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
while 1:
    if GPIO.input(4) == TRUE:
        s.sendall('1')
    if GPIO.input(4) == FALSE:
        s.sendall('0')
conn.close()

#client2 code 
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

HOST = '192.168.43.57'
PORT = 10000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
while 1:
    if GPIO.input(4) == TRUE:
        s.sendall('2')
    if GPIO.input(4) == FALSE:
        s.sendall('3')
conn.close()
```

Thanks for your attention and help before

Answer (score 0):

Didn't got your que completely, hope you mean to serve multiple clients.
From your server code, it only gets connection from 1 client and then exits.
If you wants to serve forever and 1 client at a time, you'll need something like

```
while True:
print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
connection, client_address = sock.accept()
try:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'client connected:', client_address
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(16)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
        if data:
            # Whatever server wants to do with data.
        else:
            break
finally:
    connection.close()
```

To overcome the limitation(of 1 client at a time) there are several strategies. One of them involves making the server multi-threaded. Create threads for each accepted  connections, and a handler to actually process the data.

Also you have some spell mistakes :

) blind => bind

) Client is connected via variable "s" but you are closing conn.